# How do I find the coordinates of a address?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am making a app that places a point on the coordinates of an address using MapKit.

I have my class made and all my functions set up within the class.

I need to be able to return "getLocation()" which will be the string of an address and use that string with the CLGeoCoder().geocodeAdressString and get the coordinates.

Here are my classes

```
import UIKit

class Vendor {

    private var name = String()
    private var type = String()
    private var location = String()
    private var logo = UIImage()

    required init(name: String, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.location = ""
        self.logo = UIImage()
    }


    func getName() -> String {
        return self.name
    }
    func setName(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }


    func getType() -> String {
        return self.type
    }
    func setType(type: String) {
        self.type = type
    }

    func getLocation() -> String {
        return self.location
    }
    func setLocation(address: String) {
        self.location = address
    }

    func getLogo() -> UIImage {
        return self.logo
    }
    func setLogo(image: UIImage) {
        self.logo = image
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your geocoding code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the location in your vendor class are the street, city and country of the vendor your code might look something like this:

```
    func geoCodeVendor() {

    let vendorLocation = myVendor.getLocation
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(vendorLocation) { (placemarks, error) in

        self.centerCoordinate = (placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate)!
        //Whather more you want to do in this completion handler.

    }
}
```

Here you have created an instance of Vendor, myVendor in the class where you are geocoding your vendor. In that class you have created a property centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D().

Usually, you have a vendor class with the name, address and city in separate properties. For instance:

```
class Vendor {

    private var name = String()
    private var type = String()
    private var address = String()
    private var city = String()
    private var logo = UIImage()
}
```

Then your append the address and city in your getLocation function. Please, remind that geocoding works more accurate when the address is as complete as possible, That is, address (with number, city, country.

Hope this helps.